# Visit visa to Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, saudi-arabia

My father (a Yemeni citizen) is resident in Saudi Arabia with a long-term working visa (iqama). I have a Swedish travelling document and would like to visit my father in Saudi Arabia. According to [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Saudi_Arabia):

> Tourist visas, previously available for groups of at least four on guided tours, were "suspended" in late 2010 permanently.

If a Tourist visa is not available, is there some other legitimate way for me to achieve a short family visit?

Comment: your father has "iqama" means he is not saudi national, he is there on a working visa. what is your your and your father nationality?

Comment: Apparently the Kingdom has or is about to resume issuing tourist visas, you might want to look into that, which might still be called a visit visa?

Comment: also you can visit your father on "umrah visa"? you thought about it?

Comment: @AliAwan: It seems safe to assume OP is muslim but you never know. Do you need to be muslim to apply for an umrah visa?

Comment: yes i thought about it because of his name mohammad, usually it is a muslim name. Umrah visa is specially for muslims for visitng religion holy mark KABAH

Comment: Umra visa is really short and I don't know if I can come with a business visa or work visa because of my passport status

Comment: @AliAwan my dad is yemeni

Comment: @ Mohammed al-Rabea your dad can arrange a visit visa through your dad kafeel(sponsor), ask your dad about this

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what category of visa your dad has, he can apply for a visit visa for you.

You would need:

1. A passport (or travel document) valid for 6 months.
2. Photos (white background)
3. Fees
4. A copy of your father's iqama (the resident card) which should be current. Keep in mind in Saudi they use Hijri dates - today is 15/01/1438.
5. A copy of the printout from the MOFA visa website; which shows your visa type, duration and the fact that the application has been accepted.

Your father needs to do the following:

1. Go online to the MOFA website, or to his company's department that handles employee affairs and submit a copy of his passport and residency.
2. A copy of your travel document's ID page.
3. Pay the relevant fees.
4. Pay the mandatory $254 medical insurance (new rule, enacted yesterday); payable only through the Enjaz system.
5. Wait for the automated system to issue a visa.
6. Send you a printout of the visa page, or the application number.

You can print out the visa result yourself, by entering the application number and your dad's residency number at [this website](https://visa.mofa.gov.sa/).

Answer (score 4):

This is Ali Awan's comment turned into an answer: your dad can arrange a visit visa through your dad kafeel(sponsor), ask your dad about this.

Answer (score 2):

Saudi Arabia started to issue [tourist visas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Saudi_Arabia) online and on arrival from 28 September 2019.
Note that the older answers may no longer be valid because of this.